# Pandas read_json, multiple lines issue

Tags: python, json, pandas

Iam trying to read a json file, however I get a "trailing data" ValueError with

```
df = pd.read_json(pathto\json')
```

I learned that I have to use the lines=TRUE argument, however this leads to a strange combination between a dataframe and JSON:

```
df = pd.read_json(pathto\json', lines=True)
print(df)
```

```
                                                0     ...                                               6128
0  {'rt': 6014.89999999851, 'stimulus': 'Welcome ...  ...                                               None
1  {'rt': 1458.9000000003725, 'stimulus': 'Welcom...  ...  {'view_history': [{'page_index': 0, 'viewing_t...
2  {'rt': 5663.199999988079, 'stimulus': 'Welcome...  ...                                               None
3  {'rt': 2920.300000011921, 'stimulus': 'Welcome...  ...                                               None

[4 rows x 6129 columns]
```

Does somebody know who to solve this? I also tried manually removing linebreaks, but it leads to the same result.

Edit: Also, if I only read one line of the file, it loads properly (works for every single line):

```
with open('pathto\json', 'r') as f:
data = f.readlines()[3]
print(pd.read_json(data))
```

```
           rt  ... followsCheck
0      2920.3  ...          NaN
1     90552.4  ...          NaN
2      6501.3  ...          NaN
3     77964.3  ...          NaN
4         NaN  ...          NaN
      ...  ...          ...
6056   3990.6  ...          NaN
6057   2323.0  ...          NaN
6058      NaN  ...          NaN
6059  11882.9  ...          NaN
6060  26112.4  ...          NaN

[6061 rows x 40 columns]
```

Comment: What does your JSON file look like? It is likely this is in a format that is not practical for Pandas to read properly.

Comment: The file has one JSON object per line. Looks good.

Also, if I only read one line of the file, it loads properly

Comment: Can you provide a small sample json (maybe with 2/3 lines) that reproduces the error?

Comment: Sure. https://github.com/Schiwo/Sharing/blob/main/json.txt

Comment: Your file is neither JSON, nor line-based JSON objects. The first line ends about a quarter of the total file size (hence you see only four rows when you use `lines=True`). It isn't proper JSON, but appears to be several JSON files concatenated.

Comment: Oh, I guess I had a wrong impression how a data frame should look like in JSON. So, basically I have to read every single line of my file, since they all represent seperate JSONs, and afterwards I can merge the data frames?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: File included multiple JSON-objects.

```
with open('pathto\json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = map(lambda x: pd.read_json(x), data)
df = pd.concat(data)

print(df)
```

```
           rt  ... followsCheck
0      6014.9  ...          NaN
1      4832.0  ...          NaN
2      4801.8  ...          NaN
3     41796.2  ...          NaN
4         NaN  ...          NaN
      ...  ...          ...
6056   3990.6  ...          NaN
6057   2323.0  ...          NaN
6058      NaN  ...          NaN
6059  11882.9  ...          NaN
6060  26112.4  ...          NaN

[24323 rows x 40 columns]
```

Thank you, guys! =)